# How to search and insert multiple nodes in Linked List

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, linked-list, doubly-linked-list

I am trying to search for nodes, where the output i.e result of nodes is more than one. So i am trying to make a new doubly linked list and add those new nodes into it. 
However only get 1 correct result, the second gives me I guess address or that node or is error. as shown in the image.

[image]

my code:

```
Order::Node* Order::searchByDate(string date) {
    Node* cur = head;
    Node* node = NULL;
    cout << "\nSearching " << endl;
    Sleep(400);

    while (cur != NULL) {
        if (cur->date == date) {
            //create new node
            Node* newNode = new Node;
            newNode->prev = NULL;
            newNode->next = cur;
            //copy newNode to node(new linked list having all search result)
            node = newNode;
            node->prev = newNode;
            node = newNode;
            Sleep(400);
        }

        cur = cur->next;
    }
    return node;
}
```

Display function:

```
Node* cur = searchByDate(date);
while (cur != NULL) {
    cout << cur->orderid << "\t\t" << cur->date << "\t" << cur->cust.custId << endl;
    cur = cur->next;
}
```

Any solution that I can add all the searched nodes into one linked list.

Comment: Why the Sleep(400)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The new node's

- previous should the existing search results.
- next should be null.

For the existing search results

- next should point to the new node.

Keep another pointer to the start of the search results. Return this start node as the result of the method.

Try this

```
Order::Node* Order::searchByDate(string date) {
    Node* cur = head;
    Node* node = NULL;
    Node* start = NULL;

    while (cur != NULL) {
        if (cur->date == date) {

            //make a new node
            Node* newNode = new Node(cur->date);
            newNode->prev = NULL; //explicitly set to NULL
            newNode->next = NULL; //explicitly set to NULL

            if (node == NULL) {
                //very first node
                node = newNode;
                start = node;
            }
            else {
                //append new node to existing nodes
                //see diagram below
                node->next = newNode;
                newNode->prev = node;
                node = newNode;
            }
        }

        cur = cur->next;
    }
    return start;
}
```

[image: append new node]

Comment: how do you make such nice diagrams?

Comment: yes now it works. I made a slight change i.e  `Node* newNode = new Node;
   newNode->prev = NULL; //explicitly set to NULL
   newNode->next = NULL; //explicitly set to NULL
   newNode = cur;` Thank you

Comment: @V-R Visio or openoffice's draw utility are likely candidates.

Comment: @V-R yed (https://www.yworks.com/products/yed), and it's easy and fast to make diagrams

Comment: Brilliant, I so didn't want to install Visio etc :)